# stopping loops in php(break and continue not working for me)

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have some series of loops in my php for an example

//select statement

```
while (gyu_fetch($acaYear_results)) {
    $Year = gyu_get_col($Year_results,0);
    $page->main .= '<option value="'.$Year.'"';
    if ($Year!="" and $Year==$Year) { $page->main .= ' selected="selected"'; }
    $page->main .= '>'.$Year.'</option>';
}
```

//select statment

```
 while(gyu_fetch($domain_results)) {
    $row = gyu_get_col($results,0);
    $page->main .= '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$row.'</option>';            
 }


 if ($tui_domain != $tui_domain_old and $tui_domain_old != 'REiOl7')
 {
     $page->main .= '<tr><td colspan="4" style="background-color:#DDDDDD;">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
 }
```

In all my while loops and foreach loops I have used `break;` and `continue;` but when I used each of them in my select statements.
what happens is that my webpage will not render completely as it will only affect other if statements.

I was wondering if there are other ways to stop `while` or `if` statements from not looping over and over again but does not affect any element of the page that might be using it for example

```
  while(gyu_fetch($domain_results)) {
      $row = gyu_get_col($results,0);
      break;            
  }
  $page->main .='"'.$row.'"';
```

In that example although I have ends execution of the current `while` structure will this affect `'"'.$row.'"'` being used?

Comment: No, it will not affect `'"'.$row.'"'` being used, because you are breaking out of the `while` loop, that has nothing to do with your code after that loop.

Comment: `... render completely as it will only either other if statements.` -- what do you mean?

Comment: @AmalMurali sorry was meant to be `affect` not `either`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$row` outside the while loop as it is, since it is declared inside the loop and is thus local to it. Try initializing it before the loop ( `$row='';` ).

More on [variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: `initializing before the loop`? what about if it was like `while {   if ($t == 'oop'){ } echo 'next line'; if($h == '33') { echo 'hello';} if { echo 'bye';} else { echo 'hi' } break;}`. That is a standard example from my code in terms of how the `while` loop has if and else statement. as u normal it `echo` out strings but in my code its html tables. before the `while` closing i have a `break;` and before of this it stops the `if` statements outside that while loop from rendering... any idea why.